# Cypress Assertion

Tags: testing, autocomplete, cypress

I have a question regarding Cypress assertions, just recently start playing with this testing platform, but got stuck when the URL returns a random number as shown below.

```
/Geocortex/Essentials/REST/sites/SITE?f=json&deep=true&token=SK42f-DZ_iCk2oWE8DVNnr6gAArG277W3X0kGJL1gTZ7W5oQAAV9iC4Zng4mf0BlulglN-10NK&dojo.preventCache=1575947662312
```

As you can see **token** is random and **dojo.preventCache** is also a random string. I want to detect this url and check if **deep=true** regardless the token number, but I don't know how to achieve this.

```
cy.location('origin', {timeout: 20000}).should('contain', '/Geocortex/Essentials/REST/sites/SITE?f=json&deep=true&token=**&dojo.preventCache=**');
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can check both the path and query like this (note that `cy.location('origin')` doesn't yield neither `pathname` nor `query` from your original question, so I'm using `cy.url()`):

```js
cy.url()
    .should('contain', '/Geocortex/Essentials/REST/sites/SITE')
    .should('contain', 'deep=true');
```

or check each separately:

```js
cy.location('pathname').should('contain', '/Geocortex/Essentials/REST/sites/SITE');
cy.location('search').should('contain', 'deep=true');
```

or, use a custom callback in which you do and assert whatever you want:

```js
cy.url().should( url => {
    expect(/* do something with url, such as parse it, and access the `deep` prop */)
        .to.be.true;
});
```